# zxing barcode scanner giving notfoundexception

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Using below code, I get NotFoundException everytime. Please help.

```
 Bitmap bMap=  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyActivity.this.getResources(),
 R.drawable.barcode_dummy);

int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];

 //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array  

 bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),
                 bMap.getHeight());  

LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();// use this otherwise ChecksumException
try {
         Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
         decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
         //decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);

        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap ,decodeHints);
        if(result!=null){
           Utility.ShowToastShort(MyActivity.this,result.getText());
        }
        else{
           Utility.ShowToastShort(MyActivity.this, "Bar code couldn't be scanned");
        }
} catch (NotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
 } 
  catch (ChecksumException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
  catch (FormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
 } 

}
```

I have added zxing-2.1.jar under libs/ folder. It works when I call IntentIntegrator. [image]

Above image is the barcode_dummy in drawable/ folder.

EDIT :

I did try with below image as well.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**LOGCAT :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:

 main
E/AndroidRuntime( 9580): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webintesive.expertly/com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

`E/AndroidRuntime( 9580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

`E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):   at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.showPhotoFromImageUri(MyActivity.java:167)`

`E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):   at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.init(MyActivity.java:120)`

`E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):   at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:84)`

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)

E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):    ... 11 more

E/AppErrorDialog(  503): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Comment: could you please add your logcat?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime( 9580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):  at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.showPhotoFromImageUri(MyActivity.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):  at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.init(MyActivity.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9580):  at com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:84)

Comment: yould you please edit your question, insert the full logcat and highlight that line `com.webintesive.expertly.MyActivity.showPhotoFromImageUri(MyActivity.java:167)` in your code+

Comment: That is a `NullPointerException`, not `NotFoundException`. Clarify what your problem is.

Comment: When I debug the code, the control goes to catch (NotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
 } and then application gets stopped.

Comment: @SeanOwen can you please help what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

`NotFoundException` is normal. It means no barcode was found in the image. You have to handle this, yes. Your image is rotated 90 degrees and by default barcodes are looked for in normal orientation.

You should indeed use `IntentIntegrator` if you can. It works, and saves you from having to figure out again all of these things.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick response. I can't go with IntentIntegrator as per my requirement.I need to scan saved image from gallery.How could I perform it with IntentIntegrator ?

Comment: Finally got it working. Barcode wasn't detectable by barcode scanner either which I was using. Ran above code for image with detectable barcode, it worked like charm. Thanks !